# Not able to play YouTube Video in Webview

Tags: video, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, youtube-api

Can somebody help me how to get rid of this :

I am using this code which works fine :

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe39vPFabuA", 64.0, 64.0];
    [wbView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

But problem arises when I replace Youtube URL string with some other string, For example : http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL93D60DC1974BCD1E&hl=en_US

**How can I play above link youtube video in WebView.**

I had tried it with several ways :

1. Replacing the "/embed/" with "/watch?v="
2. Simply removing the hl=en_US from String.

But everything in vain. What do I need to do & make it running in iPhone. How can I play the video?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to load a playlist rather than a single video. This is the link to the actual video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvlgRV0PoUc&feature=plcp

However it seems that this video is not enabled for mobile because that link loads fine on a laptop but no on the device. This setting is set by the owner of the video on Youtube.